# Error 500 en Laravel 7 de ruta no definida que si existe

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, routes

Tengo una ruta GET, tal que así:

```
Route::get('permissions/{roleName?}', 'RoleController@index')
    ->name('permission.index');
```

Esta registrada. Con:

```
php artisan r:l --method=get path=permissions --compact
```

se lista:

```
+----------+-------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| Method   | URI                     | Action                                    |
+----------+-------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| GET|HEAD | permissions/{roleName?} | App\Http\Controllers\RoleController@index |
+----------+-------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
```

En el controlador, en el método `RoleController@index` recibo el parámetro *opcional* como un *string* vacío:

```
public function index(string $roleName = '')
{
    dd(111, $roleName);
}
```

Está ruta me esta *funcionando* con parámetro y sin el. Salvo que haga una redirección al mismo desde otro controlador pasándole o no el parámetro.

La ruta se genera correctamente, la he trazado antes de redireccionar. Si se copia a la barra de direcciones del navegador si funciona.

La redirección produce un error 500. Esta definida así:

```
$route = route('permissions.index', $roleName);

return redirect()->route($route)
    ->with('success', 'OK');
```

En el **fichero de logs** tengo la traza (***Si copio la ruta que no esta definida a la barra de direcciones del navegador si funciona.***):

> [2021-05-07 13:51:18] local.ERROR: Route
> [http://www.zzz.local/permissions/foo] not defined.
> {"userId":1,"exception":"[object]
> (Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException(code:
> 0): Route [http://www.zzz.local/permissions/scs] not defined. at
> /var/www/html/laravel/zzz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php:420)
> [stacktrace]
> #0 /var/www/html/laravel/zzz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Redirector.php(176):
> Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator->route()
> #1 /var/www/html/laravel/zzz/app/Http/Controllers/RoleController.php(90):
> Illuminate\Routing\Redirector->route()
> #2 /var/www/html/laravel/zzz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(54):
> App\Http\Controllers\Authorizations\RoleController->store()
> #3 /var/www/html/laravel/zzz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(45):
> Illuminate\Routing\Controller->callAction()
> #4 /var/www/html/laravel/zzz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(239):
> Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch()
> #5 /var/www/html/laravel/zzz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(196):
> Illuminate\Routing\Route->runController()
> #6 /var/www/html/laravel/zzz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(685):
> Illuminate\Routing\Route->run()
> #7 /var/www/html/laravel/zzz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(128):
> Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}()
> #8 /var/www/html/laravel/zzz/app/Http/Middleware/CheckRole.php(20): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
> #9 /var/www/html/laravel/zzz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167):
> App\Http\Middleware\CheckRole->handle()
> #10 /var/www/html/laravel/zzz/app/Http/Middleware/AfterControllersMiddleware.php(18):
> Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
> #11 /var/www/html/laravel/zzz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167):
> App\Http\Middleware\AfterControllersMiddleware->handle()
> #12 /var/www/html/laravel/zzz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php(41):

Comment: Y si le redirigís con este formato --> return redirect()->route('permissions.index', [$roleName]) ->with('success', 'OK');

Comment: @JuanRivera, se acepta un string, integer, etc cuando la ruta solo tiene un parámetro. No es ese el problema, lo he probado, también ocurre si se genera la ruta sin parámetros como he indicado

Comment: @JavierSnachez tu solución funcionaría...
Las siguiente dos redirecciones funcionan:
`return redirect(route('permissions.index', $request->name)); 
return redirect()->route('permissions.index', $request->name);` También: `$route = route('permissions.index', $request->name);
 return redirect($route);`